# Separar en lineas para un campo de texto por numero con css y html?

Tags: html, html5, css3

Estoy intentando hacer un campo numerico separando cada numero en cada linea de la siguiente forma:

```
.input-numb{
    letter-spacing: 30px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;

    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 40px 1px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

<input type="text" maxlength="4" class="input-numb">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro centrar en cada linea en el texto?

Si hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo agradezco.

Comment: Utiliza `px` en vez de `%` en el `background-image`. Añade `background-position:bottom left` esto hará que empiece las líneas desde el principio. Añade `padding-left:5px` esto alineará el 1º Número. Añadele un `width` ya que cuando le pongas `background-position:bottom left` se verá una nueva línea. Y por último utiliza el DevTools de tu navegador para ajustarlo bien utilizando el `letter-spacing` y los `px` de `background-image`. A mi se me ha alineado con `font-size:16px;width:140px;letter-spaccing:31.4px;background-image:...20px....0px;background-position:bottom left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que buscabas, simplemente si quieres añadir más o menos líneas tienes que jugar con la propiedad `width`

```css
.input-numb-2 {
display: block;
  border: none;
  width: 5.5ch;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, 
        dimgrey 0, 
        dimgrey 1ch, 
        transparent 0, 
        transparent 1.5ch) 
      0 100%/100% 2px no-repeat;
  color: dimgrey;
  font: 5ch consolas, monospace;
  letter-spacing: .5ch;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input-numb-2" value="2345">
```